# PostgreSQL: CREATE FUNCTION returns one row by primary key

Tags: postgresql, return, create-function

I wrote the following function:

```
-- Authenticate: Get session_id with user_id
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sessions_get(bigint) RETURNS SETOF char(32) AS
$$
    SELECT strip_hyphens(id) as id FROM sessions WHERE user_id = $1;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

1. I want to be able to run the query `SELECT sessions_get(1)` to get the session ID with user ID 1. And, I want the name of the column returned to be `id`.

   Is that possible? Or, would the query have to be `SELECT * FROM sessions_get(1)`? In that case, it'd be shorter to just write `SELECT sessions_get(1) as id`. Which is better?
2. Can I remove `SETOF` since I know this function will always return 0 or 1 rows? I know this because `user_id` is the primary key of the `sessions` table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the function to:

   ```
   -- Authenticate: Get session_id with user_id
   CREATE FUNCTION sessions_get(bigint, OUT id char(32)) RETURNS SETOF char(32) AS
   $$
       SELECT strip_hyphens(id) FROM sessions WHERE user_id = $1;
   $$
   LANGUAGE SQL;
   ```

   Then, use the query: `SELECT * FROM sessions_get(1)`.
2. Use `SETOF` so that 0 rows are returned when none exist. Otherwise, you'll get 1 empty row.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid returning SETOF you can always do this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sessions_get(IN a bigint, OUT id char(32)) RETURNS char(32) AS
$$
    SELECT strip_hyphens(id) INTO id FROM sessions WHERE user_id = $1;
    RETURN;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Does your answer return 0 rows when there are no rows in `sessions` for a given `user_id`?